# get main URL from subdirectory with php

Tags: theme-development, urls, directory

I have a WordPress site that contains multiple subdirectory installations of WordPress with individual databases inside one WordPress installation, and I want to link them together in the themes. But I couldn't figure out how to dynamically get the main URL from the base WordPress directory for one of the subdirectories.

For example, I tried to use get_home_url() but it only returns https://mytestsite.com/instance1 instead of https://mytestsite.com

This might be something basic but i couldn't find anything in my resarch that could help me out.

Comment: Can you clarify if this is a WP Multi site? By the way you described it, it sounds like its multiple individual installs and not a multi site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`site_url` gets you the current sites URL, but you can get the site URL of the root blog at `/` via `get_site_url` by passing its ID, which is likely to be `1`, e.g.:

```php
$url = get_site_url( 1 );
```

---

As an aside, you may find `switch_to_blog` and `restore_current_blog` to be useful, just know that they're not cheap to call, and it won't load code from the other blog/site, if the other site relies on a custom plugin or filters it won't be present unless it's also present on the current site.